# How to use Active Storage to add profile picture for User

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Recently, I tried using active storage in Ruby on Rails to store profile picture for logged in user. I been following this documentation closely but, it didn't work out https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html.
What I want is to allow users to register with only first name, last name, username, password, and email. Then, users can login and they can upload their own profile picture from profile page. After uploading, I want users to see their avatar in their profile.
[image]

My User.rb Model is looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
    
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :password, presence: true

    has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

I added "has_one_attached :avatar" like from the rails documentation and I'm using "set_avatar" method to attach avatar to an existing user.
My users_controller is looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authorized
    wrap_parameters format: []

    def index
        users = User.all
        render json: users
    end

    def find_user
        user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if user
            render json: user, status: :not_found
        else
            render json: { error: "Not found" }, status: :not_found
        end
    end

    def show
        user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        if user
            render json: user
        else
            render json: { error: "Not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    def create
        user = User.create(user_params)
        if user.valid?
            session[:user_id] ||= user.id
            render json: user, status: :created
        else
            render json: {error: user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def update
        currentUser = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if currentUser
            currentUser.update(user_update_params)
            render json: currentUser, status: :accepted
        else
            render json: {error: currentUser.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def destroy
        user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if user
            user.destroy
            head :no_content
        else
            render json: {error: "user not found"}, status: :not_found
        end
    end

    def set_avatar
        user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if user
            user.avatar.attach(params[:avatar])
        else
            render json: {error: "Profile image upload failed"}
        end
    end

    private
    def user_params
        params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :username, :password, :avatar)
    end

    def user_update_params
        params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :username, :password)
    end
end
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # resources :game_memos
  # resources :memos
  # resources :games
  # resources :users
  resources :sessions
  
  #--------------USER------------------------------
  # Create Session
  get '/login', to: "sessions#create"
  # Show all users
  get '/users', to: "users#index"
  # Register new user
  post '/users', to: "users#create"
  # Login User
  post "/login", to: "sessions#create"
  # Logout user
  delete '/logout', to: "sessions#destroy"
  # Update User profile
  patch '/users/:id', to: "users#update"
  # Keep user logged in
  get '/me', to: "users#show"
  # Get request for find user based on User id
  get '/users/:id', to: "users#find_user"
  # Save avatar
  post '/users/:id', to: "users#set_avatar"

  # -------------GAMES Routes----------------------

  get '/games', to: 'games#index'
  # Show all the games that belongs to logged in user
  get '/users/:id/games', to: "games#show"
  # Create a new wishlist
  post '/games', to: "games#create"
  # Delete a game from wishlist
  delete '/users/:id/games/:id', to: "games#destroy"


  #-------------Memo Routes------------------------
  # Show memos that belongs to a game
  get '/games/:id/memos', to: "memos#show"
  # Post memos to a game
  post '/games/:id/memos', to: "memos#create"

end
```

I'm uploading my avatar from this component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// I'm getting default image from this location just for now
import IMAGES from '../images/Image';

export default function ProfilePicture({currentUser}){
    const[profileAvatar, setAvatar] = useState([])
    
    const fileTypes = [
        "image/apng",
        "image/bmp",
        "image/gif",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/pjpeg",
        "image/png",
        "image/svg+xml",
        "image/tiff",
        "image/webp",
        "image/x-icon"
      ];
   
      function handleSubmit(e){
    //     fetch(`/users/${currentUser.id}` ,{
    //         method: "POST",
    //         headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    //         body: JSON.stringify({avatar:profileAvatar})
    //     })
    //     .then((r) => r.json())
    //     .then(data => {
    //         if (data.errors) {
    //             alert(data.errors)
    //          }
    //          else {
    //             setAvatar(data)
    //          }
    //     })
      }

    return(
        <div> 
            <img src={IMAGES.defaultProfile} alt="default_profile_image" className="profile_avatar"/>       
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" accept={fileTypes} onChange={(e)=>setAvatar(e.target.value)}/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>       
        </div>
    )
}
```

Lastly, my Users migration file:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :username
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :avatar
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I wasn't sure where to ask this kind of question. I never used Active Storage before and this is my first time using it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't need `t.string :avatar`. ActiveStorage attachments are not columns of owner table but records in associated tables

ActiveStorage provides Direct Upload if you use JS frameworks like React

[From docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#integrating-with-libraries-or-frameworks):

> If you want to use the Direct Upload feature from a JavaScript framework, or you want to integrate custom drag and drop solutions, you can use the `DirectUpload` class for this purpose. Upon receiving a file from your library of choice, instantiate a DirectUpload and call its create method. Create takes a callback to invoke when the upload completes.
>
> ```js
> import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage"
>
> const input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]')
>
> // Bind to file drop - use the ondrop on a parent element or use a
> //  library like Dropzone
> const onDrop = (event) => {
>   event.preventDefault()
>   const files = event.dataTransfer.files;
>   Array.from(files).forEach(file => uploadFile(file))
> }
>
> // Bind to normal file selection
> input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
>   Array.from(input.files).forEach(file => uploadFile(file))
>   // you might clear the selected files from the input
>   input.value = null
> })
>
> const uploadFile = (file) => {
>   // your form needs the file_field direct_upload: true, which
>   //  provides data-direct-upload-url
>   const url = input.dataset.directUploadUrl
>   const upload = new DirectUpload(file, url)
>
>   upload.create((error, blob) => {
>     if (error) {
>       // Handle the error
>     } else {
>       // Add an appropriately-named hidden input to the form with a
>       //  value of blob.signed_id so that the blob ids will be
>       //  transmitted in the normal upload flow
>       const hiddenField = document.createElement('input')
>       hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
>       hiddenField.setAttribute("value", blob.signed_id);
>       hiddenField.name = input.name
>       document.querySelector('form').appendChild(hiddenField)
>     }
>   })
> }
> ```

Pay attention to `const url = input.dataset.directUploadUrl`. You need to set `data-direct-upload-url` attribute as your upload url, by default it is `/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads`

`hiddenField.setAttribute("value", blob.signed_id)` from this example is a Rails magic

When the file is uploaded, Rails return blob with signed_id to frontend. Using it, you can attach file to the record

In your case

```
fetch(`/users/${currentUser.id}`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({avatar: blob.signed_id}) // blob.signed_id we get after file uploading
})
```

On backend

```
def set_avatar
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.update(avatar: params[:avatar])
  render json: { avatar: rails_blob_path(user.avatar) }
end
```

So pass blob.signed_id and avatar will be attached automatically

Probably [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jennyjean8675309/connect-your-react-application-to-a-rails-api-using-active-storage-part-2-84e7978ba11d) will be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Like Mechnicov's answer you don't need `t.string :avatar`
in the schema the
 `has_one_attached :avatar` is already taking care of that.

If you want to attach the photo through the backend and not direct upload try using this

```
user.avatar.attach(io: file, filename: 'photo.png', content_type: 'image/png')
```

and make sure that the client is sending the photo through formdata and not through the body

**Step 1:** Create a FormData instance

`let formData = new FormData();`

**Step 2:** Append the data in it

```
formData.append('file_to_upload', fileRef.files[0]);   //  fileRef is the input file reference
```